# How to create multipe labels on polygons?

Tags: qgis, labeling

Is there any tool or function to create muliple labels on polygons?

[image]

Edit:

Meanwhile I've created a point layer for label placement using the refFunctions plugin.

```
geomwithin('polygon', 'label')
```

Unfortunately QGIS gets quite slow having a few hundred point features.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know there is no such tool. The work-around is to either split the polygon into multiple polygons or create a point layer for label placement.

The spatial join approach you've posted has to be slow since it does not take advantage of any spatial index thus looping through all features every time.

Comment: How to add a spatial index? Is there any way creating a scale-based spatial join?

Comment: At small scales there is no need for labeling the polygons.

Comment: Nice workaround Underdark. there is a link http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31207/generate-random-points-in-selected-areas-for to creating random points to intersect with the polygon for a more *natural* feel.