# PostGIS "Overlay" Style Union, not "Dissolve" Style

Tags: postgis, geoprocessing, style, union

I'm trying to use PostGIS to do a 'union' of polygons. When I Googled "PostGIS Union", I found the ST_Union function, which performs what I would call a 'dissolve,' not a Union. What I actually want to do is what GRASS refers to as an "Overlay" with the "OR" operator, or QGIS/ArcGIS just simply call a "Union." For example:

[image]

From what I can tell, in PostGIS it appears I need to use both ST_Intersection and ST_SymDifference together to get the results I am seeking. I have had some success with the following syntax, but it's terribly inefficient. Is there a better/more efficient way to do what I'm hoping to accomplish?

```
INSERT INTO "CombinedResults" ("geom")
SELECT ST_SymDifference(
        "test1".GEOM
        ,"test2".GEOM
        )
    FROM "test1","test2";

INSERT INTO "CombinedResults" ("geom")
SELECT ST_Intersection(
        "test1".GEOM
        ,"test2".GEOM
        )
    FROM "test1","test2"
```

Comment: Check out this solution from a while back: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/785/18189

Comment: Also this one: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109692/how-to-replicate-arcgis-intersect-in-postgis

Answer (score -1):

Maybe [ST_ConvexHull](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_ConvexHull.html) will help you. See this snippet to understand how it works http://www.bostongis.com/postgis_concavehull.snippet

Comment: This is not a definitive answer, also the relevant information from the link should be provided in the answer in order to mitigate link rot