# Symmetrical difference between two layers using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, symmetric-difference

This question is related to [Seeking PostGIS equivalent to GeoPandas union overlay?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/302433)

I have two tables in PostGIS, each with two features(rows) and a rectangular geometry (polygon).

[image]

I would like to obtain the Symmetrical Difference from those two layers so that the result would be:

[image]

the resulting table has the attributes from the first table (df1), or the second (df2)

[image]

However when I try to use ST_SymDifference in PostGIS I get a different result:

```
CREATE TABLE test.symdifference_v04 AS
SELECT 
    test.df1.df1,
    test.df2.df2,
    ST_SymDifference(test.df1.geom,test.df2.geom)
FROM test.df1, test.df2
```

[image]

It seems that the ST_SymDifference is applied on a polygon to polygon basis i.e. df1 row 1 vs df2 row 1
df1 row 1 vs df2 row 2
df1 row 2 vs df2 row 1
df1 row 2 vs df2 row 2

with Multipolygons as a result.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

How would I obtain the first mentioned result with the 6 polygons (fancy colors) instead of the 4 multiploygons in PostGIS?

Answer (score 3):

This query should help you solve the problem:

variant 1 -

1) Create wanted parts:

`CREATE TABLE table_cut as
SELECT DISTINCT a.id, ST_Difference(a.geom, b.geom) AS geom
FROM table1 AS a JOIN table2 AS b
ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
GROUP BY a.id, a.geom, b.geom;`

`CREATE TABLE table_cut2 as
SELECT DISTINCT a.id, ST_Difference(a.geom, b.geom) AS geom
FROM table2  AS a JOIN table1  AS b
ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
GROUP BY a.id, a.geom, b.geom;`

`CREATE TABLE table_cut1 as
SELECT DISTINCT a.id, ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom) AS geom
FROM table1 AS a JOIN table2 AS b
ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
GROUP BY a.id, a.geom, b.geom;`

2) Create a results tables

`CREATE TABLE table3 AS
SELECT DISTINCT a.id, (ST_Dump(ST_Difference(a.geom, b.geom))).geom
FROM table_cut2 a JOIN table_cut1 b
ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
GROUP BY a.id, a.geom, b.geom;`

`CREATE TABLE table4 AS
SELECT DISTINCT a.id, (ST_Dump(ST_Difference(a.geom, b.geom))).geom
FROM table_cut a JOIN table_cut1 b
ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
GROUP BY a.id, a.geom, b.geom`

3) Remove the two internal parts and symbolize the cells ...

[image]

Interesting geometric puzzle: -) ...

option 2 -

```
WITH
tbla AS (SELECT * FROM table1 UNION SELECT * FROM table2),
tblb AS (SELECT a.id, ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom) AS geom FROM table1 AS a JOIN table2 AS b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom) GROUP BY a.id, a.geom, b.geom)
(SELECT a.id, (ST_Dump(ST_Difference(a.geom, b.geom))).geom AS geom FROM tbla AS a CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT ST_Collect(geom) AS geom FROM tblb WHERE ST_Intersects(a.geom, geom)) AS b);
```

...

Comment: can you style your comment please?

Comment: the result is almost correct except that there is no middle hole.

Comment: use postgis_version 2.5; postgis_version 2.2 gives the result of four figures ... most likely the behavior function st_difference has been improved ...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `st_difference` to get your result:

First we create our two dummy tables:

```
-- FIRST SET OF POLYGON
CREATE TABLE rect1 (name varchar, geom geometry);

INSERT INTO rect1 VALUES
  (1, 'POLYGON((0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 1, 0 0))'),
  (2, 'POLYGON((1 1, 2 1, 2 2, 1 2, 1 1))');

SELECT name, ST_AsText(geom) FROM rect1;

-- SECOND SET OF POLYGON
CREATE TABLE rect2 (name varchar, geom geometry);

INSERT INTO rect2 VALUES
  (1, 'POLYGON((0.5 0.5, 1.5 0.5, 1.5 1.5, 0.5 1.5, 0.5 0.5))'),
  (2, 'POLYGON((1.5 1.5, 2.5 1.5, 2.5 2.5, 1.5 2.5, 1.5 1.5))');

SELECT name, ST_AsText(geom) FROM rect2;
```

Now we can produce the result by using `st_difference` two time:

1. The difference between rect1 and rect2
2. The difference between rect2 and rect1

Noticed that we have to group all the "cutting" geometry with `st_union`.

```
WITH T1 AS
(
    SELECT st_difference(r1.geom,st_union(r2.geom)) as geom
    FROM rect1 r1, rect2 r2
    GROUP BY r1.geom

    UNION

    SELECT st_difference(r2.geom,st_union(r1.geom)) as geom
    FROM rect1 r1, rect2 r2
    GROUP BY r2.geom
)
SELECT (st_dump(geom)).geom from T1
```

We use `ST_Dump` to split our multipart polygon to singlepart polygon.

As expected we obtain:

[image]

Comment: +1 "Noticed that we have to group all the "cutting" geometry with st_union"...