# How can I use ST_Contains/ST_Overlaps with non-simple lines?

Tags: postgis, line, overlapping-features, simplify

Following the SQL of the accepted answer to [How to get smallest line segments from intersection + difference of multiple overlapping lines?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/187031/36886) copied below. I'm having some difficulties assign the `id`s of the original linestrings to the smaller segments when the original lines are complex/self-intersect.

```
WITH smallest_segments AS (
  SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_Split(ST_Union(geom), ST_Union(ST_Boundary(geom))))).*
  FROM stackex
)
SELECT row_number() over() AS rn, join_id, s.geom AS segment
FROM smallest_segments s, LATERAL (
  SELECT string_agg(id::text, '+') AS join_id
  FROM stackex a
  WHERE ST_Contains(a.geom, s.geom)
) l;
```

Here is some sample data

```
SELECT id, geom INTO stackex FROM (VALUES
(1,ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-71.059844 42.359287,-71.059851 42.359347,-71.059869 42.359462,-71.059891 42.359577,-71.059924 42.359691,-71.059992 42.359825,-71.060053 42.359945,-71.060132 42.360065,-71.06021 42.360174,-71.060324 42.360305,-71.060451 42.360426,-71.060581 42.360533,-71.060738 42.360638,-71.060912 42.360729,-71.061131 42.360824,-71.061316 42.3609,-71.061446 42.360944,-71.061609 42.360995,-71.061797 42.361053,-71.062012 42.361107,-71.062251 42.361149,-71.062469 42.361172,-71.062671 42.361182,-71.062881 42.361182,-71.062864 42.361306,-71.062873 42.361305,-71.063716 42.36129,-71.063829 42.361286,-71.064383 42.361273,-71.064554 42.361267,-71.064752 42.36126,-71.065046 42.361246,-71.065518 42.361243,-71.066361 42.361237,-71.066855 42.361233,-71.066972 42.361232,-71.067855 42.361222,-71.068729 42.3612,-71.069896 42.361168,-71.069996 42.361178,-71.070086 42.361206,-71.070309 42.361312,-71.070396 42.361348,-71.07047 42.361371,-71.070593 42.361399,-71.070682 42.361407,-71.070784 42.361406,-71.071159 42.361377,-71.071302 42.361365,-71.071599 42.361342,-71.071724 42.361336,-71.071857 42.361335,-71.071991 42.361342,-71.079054 42.361867,-71.079214 42.361879,-71.079781 42.36192,-71.081515 42.362062,-71.082379 42.362124,-71.082457 42.362127,-71.082596 42.362121,-71.082787 42.362105,-71.08289 42.362102,-71.082972 42.3621,-71.083065 42.362102,-71.083164 42.362107,-71.083245 42.362115,-71.083318 42.362126,-71.08339 42.362139,-71.083362 42.362082,-71.083343 42.362004,-71.083335 42.361956,-71.083299 42.361998,-71.083343 42.362004,-71.083362 42.362082,-71.08339 42.362139,-71.083318 42.362126,-71.083245 42.362115,-71.083164 42.362107,-71.083065 42.362102,-71.082972 42.3621,-71.08289 42.362102,-71.082787 42.362105,-71.082596 42.362121,-71.082457 42.362127,-71.082379 42.362124,-71.081515 42.362062,-71.079781 42.36192,-71.079214 42.361879,-71.079054 42.361867,-71.071991 42.361342,-71.071857 42.361335,-71.071724 42.361336,-71.071599 42.361342,-71.071412 42.361355,-71.071302 42.361365,-71.071159 42.361377,-71.071111 42.361324,-71.071079 42.36127,-71.071024 42.361124,-71.07098 42.361043,-71.070904 42.360956,-71.070738 42.360909,-71.070639 42.360892,-71.070533 42.360886,-71.070432 42.360888,-71.070312 42.360906,-71.070215 42.36093,-71.070131 42.360969,-71.07004 42.361024,-71.070037 42.360904)')),(2,ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-71.096246 42.379862,-71.09602 42.379769,-71.095897 42.379759,-71.09579 42.379721,-71.095696 42.379711,-71.095567 42.379631,-71.094337 42.379181,-71.094215 42.379133,-71.094105 42.379098,-71.093998 42.379063,-71.093871 42.379016,-71.093568 42.378902,-71.093098 42.378718,-71.092866 42.378635,-71.092589 42.378536,-71.092457 42.37849,-71.09222 42.378412,-71.091857 42.378292,-71.091043 42.377988,-71.090633 42.377845,-71.090162 42.377677,-71.089803 42.377519,-71.089267 42.377284,-71.089231 42.37715,-71.089155 42.37687,-71.089119 42.376737,-71.089046 42.376428,-71.088948 42.376189,-71.08878 42.37582,-71.088424 42.374964,-71.08837 42.37484,-71.088206 42.374496,-71.08806 42.374156,-71.088005 42.374087,-71.087935 42.374024,-71.087647 42.373768,-71.087408 42.373597,-71.086987 42.373276,-71.086892 42.373205,-71.086461 42.373053,-71.085213 42.372581,-71.08462 42.37236,-71.0841 42.372297,-71.083721 42.372251,-71.082967 42.372147,-71.0822 42.372045,-71.081339 42.371928,-71.080508 42.371821,-71.07968 42.371713,-71.079483 42.371687,-71.078441 42.371551,-71.078348 42.371544,-71.078273 42.371549,-71.078209 42.371559,-71.078109 42.37158,-71.078051 42.371593,-71.077812 42.371524,-71.077679 42.371474,-71.077649 42.371428,-71.077609 42.371344,-71.077547 42.371298,-71.077039 42.371037,-71.07682 42.370929,-71.076696 42.370865,-71.076636 42.370833,-71.076704 42.370689,-71.076743 42.370606,-71.076923 42.370636,-71.077066 42.370027,-71.076948 42.370011,-71.076612 42.369967,-71.076434 42.369943,-71.076071 42.369895,-71.075759 42.369854,-71.075704 42.370107,-71.075604 42.370097,-71.075499 42.370076,-71.075384 42.370042,-71.075275 42.37,-71.075164 42.370125,-71.075048 42.370066,-71.075106 42.370002,-71.075339 42.369745,-71.075434 42.369644,-71.0755 42.369575,-71.074016 42.368801,-71.073904 42.368744,-71.074023 42.368623,-71.074104 42.368683,-71.07458 42.368927,-71.074761 42.369029,-71.075029 42.369173,-71.075452 42.369373,-71.075561 42.369422,-71.075656 42.369372,-71.075723 42.369405,-71.075824 42.36943,-71.07588 42.369436,-71.075981 42.369434,-71.076043 42.369424,-71.076141 42.369393,-71.076255 42.369322,-71.076335 42.369221,-71.076362 42.369108,-71.076334 42.368994,-71.076284 42.368923,-71.076222 42.368869,-71.07614 42.368823,-71.076031 42.36879,-71.075927 42.368779,-71.075777 42.368795,-71.075693 42.368823,-71.075643 42.368848,-71.07558 42.368892,-71.075522 42.368955,-71.075472 42.368997,-71.0754 42.369006,-71.074722 42.368664,-71.074738 42.368644,-71.074684 42.368616,-71.073908 42.36821,-71.073819 42.368107,-71.073285 42.36783,-71.073279 42.367777,-71.073694 42.367346,-71.073752 42.367329,-71.073824 42.367329,-71.073819 42.367382,-71.073818 42.36744,-71.073823 42.367496,-71.073835 42.367552,-71.073854 42.367604,-71.073888 42.367656,-71.073933 42.36771,-71.073998 42.367776,-71.074039 42.367828,-71.074061 42.367872,-71.074095 42.367956,-71.074108 42.368044,-71.074072 42.36812,-71.074016 42.368175,-71.073631 42.368547,-71.073473 42.368663,-71.073246 42.368884,-71.07313 42.368912,-71.073012 42.368925,-71.072884 42.368907,-71.072799 42.368884,-71.072423 42.36871,-71.071684 42.368346,-71.070729 42.367864,-71.06967 42.367319,-71.069505 42.367236,-71.069279 42.367122,-71.069057 42.367012,-71.06842 42.366678,-71.068738 42.366384,-71.068813 42.366349,-71.069353 42.365872,-71.069455 42.365784,-71.069493 42.365744,-71.069532 42.36569,-71.069597 42.365572,-71.069771 42.36521,-71.070027 42.36468,-71.070385 42.363923,-71.070428 42.363848,-71.070477 42.363778,-71.070549 42.3637,-71.070625 42.36363,-71.070702 42.363574,-71.071661 42.362957,-71.071911 42.362792,-71.072016 42.362712,-71.072111 42.362621,-71.072326 42.362366,-71.072459 42.362204,-71.072504 42.362154,-71.072619 42.362009,-71.072681 42.361914,-71.072742 42.361785,-71.072789 42.361662,-71.072824 42.361553,-71.072896 42.361145,-71.0729 42.361067,-71.072902 42.360992,-71.072896 42.36094,-71.072878 42.36089,-71.072836 42.360803,-71.072739 42.360652,-71.072774 42.360644,-71.072867 42.36062,-71.072989 42.360564,-71.073046 42.360629,-71.072927 42.360679,-71.07284 42.360716,-71.072753 42.360752,-71.072675 42.360778,-71.072594 42.360801,-71.072501 42.360825,-71.072409 42.360842,-71.072305 42.360861,-71.072174 42.360879,-71.07208 42.360885,-71.071981 42.360887,-71.071824 42.360885,-71.071608 42.360867,-71.071496 42.360881,-71.071728 42.360926,-71.071778 42.360826,-71.071563 42.360887,-71.071445 42.360903,-71.07133 42.360907,-71.071134 42.360883,-71.071145 42.36082,-71.071024 42.360804,-71.070882 42.360786,-71.070687 42.360781,-71.07052 42.360802,-71.070407 42.360848,-71.070312 42.360906,-71.070215 42.36093,-71.070131 42.360969,-71.07004 42.361024,-71.069965 42.361058,-71.069888 42.361072,-71.069808 42.361075,-71.06946 42.361076,-71.068745 42.36109,-71.068257 42.3611,-71.067856 42.361109,-71.066958 42.361118,-71.066383 42.361128,-71.066002 42.361129,-71.065515 42.361134,-71.065156 42.361136,-71.064557 42.361147,-71.064152 42.361156,-71.063816 42.361166,-71.063723 42.361168,-71.06337 42.361176,-71.062881 42.361182,-71.062671 42.361182,-71.062469 42.361172,-71.062251 42.361149,-71.062012 42.361107,-71.061797 42.361053,-71.061609 42.360995,-71.061446 42.360944,-71.061316 42.3609,-71.061131 42.360824,-71.060912 42.360729,-71.060738 42.360638,-71.060581 42.360533,-71.060451 42.360426,-71.060324 42.360305,-71.06021 42.360174,-71.060132 42.360065,-71.060053 42.359945,-71.059992 42.359825,-71.059924 42.359691,-71.059891 42.359577,-71.059869 42.359462,-71.059851 42.359347,-71.059847 42.359226,-71.059849 42.359137,-71.059859 42.359026,-71.059874 42.358941,-71.059892 42.358831,-71.059952 42.358715,-71.060021 42.358589)')),(3,ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-71.069246 42.361184,-71.069896 42.361168,-71.069996 42.361178,-71.070086 42.361206,-71.070309 42.361312,-71.070396 42.361348,-71.07047 42.361371,-71.070593 42.361399,-71.070682 42.361407,-71.070784 42.361406,-71.071159 42.361377,-71.071302 42.361365,-71.071599 42.361342,-71.071724 42.361336,-71.071857 42.361335,-71.071991 42.361342,-71.079054 42.361867,-71.079214 42.361879,-71.079781 42.36192,-71.081515 42.362062,-71.082379 42.362124,-71.082457 42.362127,-71.082596 42.362121,-71.082787 42.362105,-71.08289 42.362102,-71.082972 42.3621,-71.083065 42.362102,-71.083164 42.362107,-71.083245 42.362115,-71.083318 42.362126,-71.08339 42.362139,-71.083362 42.362082,-71.083343 42.362004,-71.083299 42.361998,-71.083189 42.361983,-71.082914 42.361964,-71.082808 42.361955,-71.080547 42.361784,-71.080422 42.361774,-71.080316 42.361644,-71.080395 42.361475,-71.081293 42.361237,-71.0815 42.361175,-71.081621 42.361137,-71.081657 42.361198,-71.081939 42.361646,-71.081901 42.361714,-71.081979 42.361766,-71.081963 42.361926,-71.082486 42.361966,-71.082655 42.361998,-71.082723 42.362034,-71.082787 42.362105,-71.082596 42.362121,-71.082457 42.362127,-71.082379 42.362124,-71.081515 42.362062,-71.079781 42.36192,-71.079214 42.361879,-71.079054 42.361867,-71.074732 42.361547,-71.071991 42.361342,-71.071857 42.361335,-71.071724 42.361336,-71.071599 42.361342,-71.071302 42.361365,-71.071159 42.361377,-71.071111 42.361324,-71.071079 42.36127,-71.071024 42.361124,-71.07098 42.361043,-71.070904 42.360956,-71.070738 42.360909,-71.070639 42.360892,-71.070533 42.360886,-71.070432 42.360888,-71.070312 42.360906,-71.070215 42.36093,-71.070131 42.360969,-71.07004 42.361024,-71.070037 42.360984)'))
as a(id,geom)
```

### What I've tried

- `ST_MakeValid` on the original lines
- `(ST_DUMP(ST_Node(geom))).geom` on the original lines
- Use `ST_LineMerge` in `ST_Split(ST_LineMerge(ST_Union(geom)), ST_Union(ST_Boundary(geom)))`
- Using `ST_Overlaps` on the segments that don't join with `ST_Contains`, this joins 4 segments, but leaves 4 unjoined

The code for that last is

```
WITH smallest_segments AS (
  SELECT (ST_Dump(split_line_multipoint(ST_Union(ST_MakeValid(geom)), ST_Union(ST_Boundary(geom))))).*
  FROM stackex
)
, contains as (SELECT row_number() over() AS rn, join_id, path, s.geom AS segment
FROM smallest_segements s, LATERAL (
  SELECT string_agg(id::text, '+') AS join_id
  FROM stackex a
  WHERE ST_Contains(a.geom, s.geom)
) l
)
SELECT row_number() over() AS rn, join_id, s.geom AS segment
FROM smallest_segments s, LATERAL (
  SELECT string_agg(id::text, '+') AS join_id
  FROM stackex a
  WHERE ST_Overlaps(a.geom, s.geom) 
) l
```