# How to get the area of two interesecting polygons divided into attributes on PostGIS

Tags: postgis, intersection, st-intersects

I am trying to calculate the area overlap two vector polygon layers.
I have the one based layer - soil map and I have second layer - plots.

The example below:
[image]

I would like to know how much area each class takes.

I created a few queries (one for each class) and I merged to my statistics table. But this solution is too time consuming.

```
create table class_I as (
select e.id, sum(st_area(st_intersection(g.geom,e.geom))) as area 
from plots e, soils g 
where st_intersects(g.geom,e.geom) and g.class='I'
group by e.go_id);
```

I am looking for a solution that allows me to calculate all classes at once.

I would like my output to look something like this:

```
plots || area_classI || area_classII || area_classIII
  1   ||     0       ||   52864,28   ||     0
  2   ||    128      ||      0       ||  258687,89
```

Comment: How many classes do you have?

Comment: I have eight classes.

Comment: Try this approach:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109692/how-to-replicate-arcgis-intersect-in-postgis

Comment: And see this:  http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2019/07/postgis-overlays.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the number of classes are known and only eight this is possible:

```
select tk.ogc_fid plots, 
            sum(st_area(st_intersection(ok.geom, tk.geom))) AS "total area",
            coalesce(sum(st_area(st_intersection(ok.geom, tk.geom))) FILTER (WHERE kkod=601), 0) AS "Forest", #kkod is the area class
            coalesce(sum(st_area(st_intersection(ok.geom, tk.geom))) FILTER (WHERE kkod=303), 0) AS "Rural",
            coalesce(sum(st_area(st_intersection(ok.geom, tk.geom))) FILTER (WHERE kkod=901), 0) AS "Water",
            coalesce(sum(st_area(st_intersection(ok.geom, tk.geom))) FILTER (WHERE kkod=611), 0) AS "Grassland"
            #more classes goes here

    from ok_my_riks ok #My land classes table
    join tk_rutnat tk #My plot table
    on st_intersects(ok.geom, tk.geom)
    where tk.ogc_fid in (5425, 5424, 5419, 5420) #To limit the number of plots in my test
    group by plots
```

If unknown number of classes or high number of classes then I would try tablefunc to pivot.

[image]

(But with some python pandas the pivoting gets alot easier:

```
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
 
con = psycopg2.connect(database="lmv", user="postgres", password="somepassword", host="localhost")
    
sql = "select tk.ogc_fid plots, (st_area(st_intersection(ok.geom, tk.geom))/10000)::int area, kkod::int
       from ok_my_riks ok join tk_rutnat tk
       on st_intersects(ok.geom, tk.geom) where tk.ogc_fid in (5425, 5424, 5419, 5420)"

df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, con) #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27884268/return-pandas-dataframe-from-postgresql-query-with-sqlalchemy
d = {601:'forest',303:'rural',901:'water',611:'grassland'} #From class code to class description
df['class'] = df.kkod.map(d) #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29794959/pandas-add-new-column-to-dataframe-from-dictionary
df2 = df.groupby(by=['plots','class'])['area'].sum().reset_index().pivot(index='plots', columns='class', values='area').fillna(0).astype(int)
```

[image]
)

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like you want to compute the polygon coverage overlay of the two datasets.  The standard approach for doing this in PostGIS currently is to:

- node the polygon linework using `ST_Node` or `ST_Union` (which is better to use in the latest release)
- polygonize the noded lines using `ST_Polygonize`
- determine resultant polygon parentage (if none indicates a hole) using `ST_PointOnSurface` and `ST_Contains`

This is well-described [here](http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2019/07/postgis-overlays.html).