# Overlaying a (say) 1Km x 1Km to a CartoDB or Here map

Tags: carto, grids-graticules, here-maps

Is there a simple way to add a (say) 1Km x 1Km grid layer (or overlay) to a cartoDB map or Here map so that as when zooms in or out the grid lines remain accurate. (NB. An absolute origination/reference point, while desirable, is not necessary, a consistently implemented grid is sufficient.)

Comment: You might have to create the grid first then upload it? There are solutions for that here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16374/how-to-create-a-regular-polygon-grid-in-postgis

Comment: Thank you mapBaker; that is what I was trying to avoid (hoping there was a simple solution which I was too dumb to find)

Answer (score 1):

The `CDB_RectangleGrid` may work for you.

Info about this function at http://docs.cartodb.com/tips-and-tricks.html#grid-visualization-functions

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if it's exactly what you're looking for but I saw this recently put back in the HERE JS API: https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics_api_nlp/h-map-overlay.html