# Build a polygon raster as indexing grid with SQL

Tags: postgis, query, vector-grid, indexing

According to the plugin [Indexed Vector Grid](https://demo.qgis.org/plugins/createnamedgrid/) which builds a polygon raster from shape bounds and name every cell as "A1, A2, A3 ...", I need a more advance solution, which I can use for hundreds of maps. I'm working with a PostGIS database and would like to have a (fast) SQL solution for that issue.

The final result should look like this:

[image: The final result should look like this:]

For every overview (bounding box of a city), I need a grid of 6x6 cells.

The table ('ov_boxes') of my bounding boxes looks like that:

[image: table of my bounding boxes]

Is there a SQL solution possible? Or do I have to go the python way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some posts around that mention functions for so-called fishnets. For instance: [How to create a regular polygon grid in PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16374/how-to-create-a-regular-polygon-grid-in-postgis)

With that function you could do something like:

`SELECT name, scale, id_qgis, (ST_CreateFishnet(6,6,width/6,height/6)).*
FROM boundingboxes`

You output would have numbers for columns and rows which you can easily translate into something like A1