# Creating Heatmap Based on Distance From Points

Tags: postgis, geoserver, heat-map

currently with postGIS I have created a table of point geometries at different coordinates representing cell phone towers. I would like to create a heatmap which would show the strength of the cell phone signal across the region where towers are located. So for example, create a grid and at each point in the grid first find all the cell towers within a certain radius of my grid point, then calculate the distance to each of the tower, then using this distance find a signal power value from a function based on distance, and finally plot a color value representing signal power based on combining all the distances to the points.

Is this possible in either postGIS or geoserver?

Comment: You could create a vector grid in PostGIS and use SQL to determine the values for the grid cells based on the method you describe above. From there, you can symbolize the grid using QGIS, publish the PostGIS table to Geoserver, and use the symbology from QGIS (export and upload an SLD file to Geoserver) to render your WMS service...

Comment: Here are some example functions for creating the grid: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16374/how-to-create-a-regular-polygon-grid-in-postgis