# Alternative of ST_Translate function in SQL SERVER 2016

Tags: postgis, sql-server

I am converting a PostgreSQL script into SQL SERVER 2016.

In PostGIS we use ST_Translate as given below :

geometry ST_Translate(geometry g1, float deltax, float deltay);

Is there any alternative of ST_Translate PostGIS function in SQL SERVER 2016 ?

Comment: Still don't think so...

Comment: Is there any custom script that do the same work ?

Comment: There are some hacks out there, but nothing straight forward

Comment: Can you give any reference?

Comment: just posted an answer below that has a tool/scripts you might be able to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try this tool:

**SQL Server Spatial Tools**
https://github.com/Microsoft/SQLServerSpatialTools

Which contains this function:

**SqlProjection**
This class provides an extensible access point to various projections and
inverse projections. See the file projection_example.sql for a sample of
its use. Currently supported projections are:

```
* Albers Equal Area
* Equirectangular
* Lambert Conformal Conic
* Mercator
* Oblique Mercator
* Tranverse Mercator
* Gnomonic
```