# GeoServer make layer style to show grid lines?

Tags: geoserver, sld

Is possible to create a GeoServer layer style so that gridlines (black lines in the image) of the gridset would be visible?
[image]
**Update1:** trying to achieve following view (red lines represent black gridlines in the first image) using only layer style options.
[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate more what you want to do and what you tried?

Comment: Don't fill the polygons?

Comment: Do you have the data that needs to be styled as Gridlines? or do you want the SLD to add Gridlines automatically on top of your data?

Comment: SLD to add Gridlines  on top of my data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not style to generate on the fly a regular grid.
What you can do is:

- Create a grid using whatever tool you want (last time I needed one I've used [How to create a regular polygon grid in PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16374/how-to-create-a-regular-polygon-grid-in-postgis))
- Load it as a layer and style it as a simple line (only stroke, no fill)