# Why are my icosahedron triangle subdivisions not equilateral (PostGIS)?

Tags: postgis, geodesic, st-distance, dggs

I am creating a [geodesic polyhedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_polyhedron) using PostGIS. I am dividing the [base icosahedron points (see Appendix A)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/334307604_Dymaxion_Map_Transformations_-_Technical_White_Paper), into the first level of [Class I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_polyhedron#Class_I) subdivisions.

### The setup

For simplicity let's take just the first triangle formed by these points:

```
CREATE TABLE pix (
    id bigserial
  , name text
  , geog geography(POINT,4326) -- use WGS84
);

insert into pix values (DEFAULT, 'China', st_point(122.3, 39.1));
insert into pix values (DEFAULT, 'Norway', st_point(10.53619898, 64.7));
insert into pix values (DEFAULT, 'Arabian sea', st_point(58.15770555, 10.44734504));
```

Which creates the base icosahedron triangle

[image]

The numbers of the triangle sides correspond to the row numbers shown in the table generated by this query

```
select p1.name
  , p2.name
  , st_distance(p1.geog, p2.geog) as dist
from pix p1
  cross join pix p2
where p1.id < p2.id
```

[image: table of distances between 3 points]

The points are roughly equidistant. There are small variances because the seed data above seems to have been generated assuming a sphere, not spheroid, which st_distance is returning - `use_spheroid` `false` in `st_distance` will yield much closer distances, but note that using `false` in all the presented queries does not change the problem described below.

### First level of Class I subdivision

```
insert into pix (name, geog)
select p1.name || '-' || p2.name
  , st_project(p1.geog, st_distance(p1.geog, p2.geog) / 2, st_azimuth(p1.geog, p2.geog)) as geog
from pix p1
  cross join pix p2
where p1.id < p2.id
```

The above generates the mid-points of each of the pairs of points on the original triangle

[image]

And these have the following distances, generated by this query

```
select p1.name
  , p2.name
  , st_distance(p1.geog, p2.geog) as dist
from pix p1
  cross join pix p2
where p1.id < p2.id
  and p2.id > 3
order by dist
```

[image]

### The problem

The distances of the segments 7, 8 and 9 (around 4000kms) are much longer than the distances of segments 1-6 (around 3500kms).

Why is this algorithm not creating something more close to equliateral triangles? Is my use of `st_azimuth` and `st_project` wrong? Or did I miss some more basic maths about projections of points onto spheres?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is due to the tiled icosahedron to-sphere projections. I think of this process as:

Take a normal icosahedron, all corners lie on the same sphere, and therefore, the distance is also the same, when projected on a sphere. However, if we take our non-projected icosahedron and subdivide all triangles, the generated points will not be on that sphere. When these move outwards, they will be bigger, like the redtriangles in this image.

[image: The first iteration]

Also, these constructions are used in architecture.
Using the [Geodesic dome calculator](https://www.ziptiedomes.com/geodesic-dome-calculators/2v-geodesic-dome-calculator.htm), (image from their site), we find for an edge length B of 3.5, the corresponding length for A is 3.9:

[image]

So indeed it was the mathematics that you missed.

Comment: Since posting I've had growing suspicions that that was the problem. I had been seduced by [beautiful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_polyhedron) [pictures](http://webpages.sou.edu/~sahrk/dgg/pubs/gdggs03.pdf) of seemingly regular DGGSs. The revelation from your answer is that regular DGGSs are not possible, and I am most surprised that this issue is not discussed more clearly in the literature I found. Or if I'm wrong, [how can I go about making one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/378879/generate-global-grid-of-circles-with-minimum-overlap-with-postgis)?

Comment: There are exactly 5 ways to do such a thing, that correspond to the 5 platonic solids, with 4, 6, 8, 12 or 20 circles over the entire globe. For what you want, using the icosahedral geodesic is actually a good approach. I'm not whether it will become better as you increase the number of subdivisions... My intuition says not, because the distance from the icosahedron to sphere, and thus inflation when projecting, do not improve.. [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749264/covering-earth-with-hexagonal-map-tiles)