# Using ST_SquareGrid to create grids

Tags: postgis, vector-grid

In PostGIS 3.1 the function `ST_SquareGrid(size, bounds)` generates a grid. The documentation for the functionality is available in the [docs](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/ST_SquareGrid.html). Understanding how this is done is not clear from the documentation.

I want to create a grid which overlaps with a polygon, in my case a country. The grid size should be in 1:n size of decimal grids. I plan on building grids according to a system [called quarter degree grid cells](https://no.wikipedia.org/wiki/QDGC).

[image]

The reason for this is that I am currently trying to shift most of the processing of this process to PostGIS rather than having to do the processing on FME. By pushing the processing to PostGIS I get less information back and forth between the database and FME.

How can I utilise this PostGIS functionality towards creating a relevant grid?

Comment: this could potentially point you in the right direction https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16374/creating-regular-polygon-grid-in-postgis - there are a number of responses in this thread, I have been using that of Alexander Palamarchuk which works quite well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want a 1 degree grid, make your reference system by geographic (eg 4326) and then make a 1 unit grid, with your shape providing the bounds.

```
with grid as (
  select (st_squaregrid(1, st_transform(geom,4326))).* 
  from admin0 where name = 'Canada'
) 
select st_astext(geom), i, j from grid;
```

Comment: Your example using the geographic reference system made more sense to me and unlocked it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I believe the example [here](https://info.crunchydata.com/blog/waiting-for-postgis-3.1-grid-generators) should help you.
Basically if you want to create a grid based on the bounds of a country just use the country's polygon, transformed into the CRS you want the grid to be in, and use the size you want the cells to be in.

```
SELECT (ST_SquareGrid(400000, ST_Transform(a.geom, 3857))).* 
FROM admin a  
WHERE name = 'Brazil';
```

If you want the grid cells to go a size smaller, you could select one cell from the large grid and call `ST_SquareGrid` on it.