# How to create a regular polygon grid in Openlayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, postgis

I am trying to create a grid in my map and do some calculations.

**I seen the following links:-**

[Create regular polygon grid using postgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16374/how-to-create-a-regular-polygon-grid-in-postgis)

[Create regular polygon grid inside a polygon using postgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4663/how-to-create-regular-point-grid-inside-a-polygon-in-postgis/4672#4672)

Here I understood, how to create a polygon grid using postgis spatial query.

Any one, please help me to do the same concept in Openlayers(any client side code).

My arguments are :

1. **Bounds value.** Example: new OpenLayers.Bounds(77.06173,28.50872,77.40918,28.74567)
2. **Distance between the points in the grid**. Example : 100

**My actual requirements is**

1. Create a grid on map.
2. Plot some POINTS.
3. Calculate the number of points in each grid.
4. Get the centroid(x,y) of the grid which have maximum number of points.

I just seen this code..

```
var points = new OpenLayers.Layer.PointGrid({
    isBaseLayer: true, dx: 15, dy: 15
});

var map = new OpenLayers.Map({
    div: "map",
    layers: [points],
    center: new OpenLayers.LonLat(0, 0),
    zoom: 2
});
```

Reference: [Openlayers Point Grid](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/examples/point-grid.html)

**My Queries**

1. How can I add polygon grid layer.
2. How can I set this layer in a particular bounds/extent.
3. How can I give "select" control to this layer.
4. How can I find out Number of points on a selected grid/polygon.

Note: I am using Openlayers 2.11.