# How to create regular point grid inside a polygon in Postgis without knowing cell size but cell number?

Tags: postgis, grids-graticules

I need to create a grid within a polygon like it is done in

[How to create regular point grid inside a polygon in Postgis?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4663/how-to-create-regular-point-grid-inside-a-polygon-in-postgis)

There a function is created to draw the grid points. But necessary to know is how huge the cells are or how huge is the distance between the point. In my case I don't know anything about that. I just know how much grid cells should be created. How can I solve that problem? How is it possible to create a grid without knowing the cell size but the number of cells that should be created? Does anybody can help me?

Comment: do you have a polygon geometry?

Comment: yes, input objects are a polygon geometry and the number of grid cells

Comment: ok, and is it will be ok if on the edges of polygon grid would be cutted to polygon area?

Comment: yes, thats no problem

Comment: Do you need an exact number? I suspect that it is likely with an irregular polygon as input that a small change in grid might overshoot or undershoot in some cases. You would need to write an iterative function with some initial guess for grid spacing and increase/decrease this until you are close to the cell number you are looking for.

Comment: Use [generate_series(start, stop)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html), which uses a specified number, then combine that with the geometries bounds of each dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adapt the function in the linked question.  Divide the problem into two parts:

1. Estimate the point spacing
2. Create the points

For step 1, divide `ST_Area(geom)` by the required number of points to get the area per point (I'm assuming *n* is large), then take the square root to get the separation.  So, assuming you've chosen one implementation of `makegrid(geometry, real)` from that question,

```
makegrid(geom, sqrt(ST_Area(geom) / n)
```

If you need to return exactly *n* points, adapt this inside an iterative search for the best separation.

N.B. I've assumed real-valued separation because I don't know the units of your grid.