# QGIS Python expression function - returning multiple values for use in a custom SQL query

Tags: pyqgis, sql, qgis-expression

Custom Python expression functions should return a QVariant-compatible value, which is specified in `qgsfunction.py` (https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/core/additions/qgsfunction.py).

So I guess it should be possible to return a Python array or dictionary, right?

In fact, this actually works pretty well in the QGIS Expression Builder, but not in a custom SQL query.

QGIS allows Python expression functions in custom SQL queries that follow the SQLite/SpatiaLite syntax. But how can we return multiple values here?

I have a practical example, where I like to build a dynamic point marker grid from the extent of the reference map of a given layout (grid spacing is defined in the project variable `grid_space` - i.e. 1000):

Here is the Python expression function:

```py
from qgis.core import qgsfunction,QgsProject,QgsExpressionContextUtils

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def getLayoutMapGridParam(layoutname, feature, parent):
    layout = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager().layoutByName(layoutname)
    space = QgsExpressionContextUtils.projectScope(QgsProject.instance()).variable('grid_space')
    if not space:
        space = 1000
    else:
        space = int(space)

    if layout:
        map = layout.referenceMap()
        if map:
            extent = map.extent()
            xmin = int(extent.xMinimum()/space)*space
            ymin = int(extent.yMinimum()/space)*space
            xcount = round(extent.width()/space,0)+1
            ycount = round(extent.height()/space,0)+1
            return [xmin,ymin,xcount,ycount]
    if not extent:
        return None
```

and the ***invalid*** SQL query for the virtual point grid layer:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
    r(x) AS (
        SELECT getLayoutMapGridParam('MyLayout')[0]
        UNION ALL
        SELECT x+var('grid_space') FROM r       
        LIMIT getLayoutMapGridParam('MyLayout')[2]
    ),   
    c(y) AS (
        SELECT getLayoutMapGridParam('MyLayout')[1]
        UNION ALL
        SELECT y+var('grid_space') FROM c
        LIMIT getLayoutMapGridParam('MyLayout')[3]
    ) 
SELECT row_number() over() as id,geomfromtext('POINT('||r.x||' '||c.y||')',31255) as geom /*:point:31255*/ FROM r,c
```

Does anyone have an idea how to return multiple values from a Python expression function for use in a custom SQL query?

Comment: Could you return the list as a string from your Python function and then cast it to an array in SQL?

Comment: @Matt Unfortunately SQLite has no support for arrays. A possible solution could be to return the values as a string and parse them via regular expressions in SQL. But there must be an easier way .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution I could find at the moment is to use the new SQLite JSON functions and operators (available since SQLite 3.38.0): https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html

So I changed my Python expression function to return a JSON string:

```py
from qgis.core import qgsfunction,QgsProject,QgsExpressionContextUtils

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def getLayoutMapGridParam(layoutname, feature, parent):
    layout = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager().layoutByName(layoutname)
    space = QgsExpressionContextUtils.projectScope(QgsProject.instance()).variable('grid_space')
    print(space)
    if not space:
        space = 1000
        QgsExpressionContextUtils.setProjectVariable(QgsProject.instance(), 'grid_space','1000')
    else:
        space = int(space)

    if layout:
        map = layout.referenceMap()
        if map:
            extent = map.extent()
            xmin = int(extent.xMinimum()/space)*space
            ymin = int(extent.yMinimum()/space)*space
            xcount = round(extent.width()/space,0)+1
            ycount = round(extent.height()/space,0)+1
            return '{"xmin":%s,"ymin":%s,"xcount":%s,"ycount":%s,"space":%s}' % (xmin,ymin,xcount,ycount,space)
    if not extent:
        return None
```

and modified the SQL to use JSON operators:

```
WITH RECURSIVE   
    r(x) AS (
        SELECT getLayoutMapGridParam('MyLayout') -> 'xmin'
        UNION ALL      
        SELECT x+getLayoutMapGridParam('MyLayout')->'space' FROM r
        LIMIT getLayoutMapGridParam('MyLayout') -> 'xcount'
    ),
    c(y) AS (
        SELECT getLayoutMapGridParam('MyLayout') -> 'ymin'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT y+getLayoutMapGridParam('MyLayout')->'space' FROM c
        LIMIT getLayoutMapGridParam('MyLayout') -> 'ycount'
    ) 
SELECT row_number() over() as id,geomfromtext('POINT('||r.x||' '||c.y||')',31255) as geom /*:point:31255*/ FROM r,c
```

The default grid spacing (1000) can be changed through setting the QGIS project variable `grid_space`.

BTW: I'm using QGIS 3.26.3 on Windows (SQLite 3.38.1)

> ### *** **UPDATE** ***
>
> with a small change in our SQL code we can reduce the number of calls to the PYTHON function `getLayoutMapGridParam`
>
> ```
> WITH RECURSIVE 
>    data(xmin,ymin,xcount,ycount,space) AS MATERIALIZED    
>        (SELECT
>           json->'xmin' AS xmin,
>           json->'ymin' AS ymin,
>           json->'xcount' AS xcount,
>           json->'ycount' AS ycount,
>           json->'space' AS space
>       FROM (SELECT getLayoutMapGridParam('MyLayout') AS json)),
>   r(x) AS (
>       SELECT xmin FROM data
>       UNION ALL
>       SELECT x+space FROM r,data
>       LIMIT (SELECT xcount FROM data)
>   ),  
>   c(y) AS (
>       SELECT ymin FROM data
>       UNION ALL
>       SELECT y+space FROM c,data
>       LIMIT (SELECT ycount FROM data)
>   )
> SELECT row_number() over() as id,geomfromtext('POINT('||r.x||' '||c.y||')',31255) as geom /*:point:31255*/ FROM r,c
> ```